# How to get the <i>th element of the <n>th permutation of a sequence directly (without any recursivity)?

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

Let say we have a string "ABCD" and we want to retrieve the letter in the i-th position from the n-th permutation of the string.

In this example, I know there are factorial(4) = 24 permutations and the list can be retrieved easily with itertools.permutations, which will give this:

> ['ABCD', 'ABDC', 'ACBD', 'ACDB', 'ADBC', 'ADCB', 'BACD', 'BADC', 'BCAD', 'BCDA', 'BDAC', 'BDCA', 'CABD', 'CADB', 'CBAD', 'CBDA', 'CDAB', 'CDBA', 'DABC', 'DACB', 'DBAC', 'DBCA', 'DCAB', 'DCBA']

So the function f I am looking for should return:

> f(0, n) == ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D', 'D'][n]
>
> f(1, n) == ['B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'D', 'D', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'][n]
>
> f(2, n) == ['C', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B'][n]
>
> f(3, n) == ['D', 'C', 'D', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'D', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'D', 'B', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'A'][n]

It's pretty easy for i == 0, we have f(0, n) == "ABCD"[n // 6] but finding a pattern when i increases is more and more complicated.

I don't care at all how the permutations are ordered so maybe a common pattern for every values of i can be found easily...

I'm planning to use this with a set of 256 elements and factorial(256) permutations, so computing the permutations is not an option.

Edit: I already have a function for this but it's too slow and I was wondering if some equivalent result can be found with a straightforward formula using for example bitwise operations...

Edit-2: Here is the current best solution thanks to @rici:

```
f = [factorial(i) for i in range(256)]
    
def _getElt(k, i):
    """
    Returns the <i>th element of the <k>th permutation of 0..255
    """
    table = list(range(256))

    for j in range(255, 254-i, -1):
        r, k = divmod(k, f[j])
        perm[j], perm[r] = perm[r], perm[j] 
    return perm[255 - i]
```

Edit-3: Here is a another approach using polynomial approximations to recreate the permutations, so a different formulation of the problem could be "how to recreate the polynomial's i-th coefficient for the n-th permutation?".

This is a list of n, permutation, polynomial's coefficient (and finally the permutation rebuild from the polynomial's coefficients) for N=4:

> 0 [0, 1, 2, 3] [Fraction(0, 1), Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(0, 1), Fraction(0, 1)] [0, 1, 2, 3]
>
> 1 [0, 1, 3, 2] [Fraction(0, 1), Fraction(-3, 4), Fraction(5, 2), Fraction(-2, 3)] [0, 1, 3, 2]
>
> 2 [0, 2, 1, 3] [Fraction(0, 1), Fraction(11, 2), Fraction(-9, 2), Fraction(1, 1)] [0, 2, 1, 3]
>
> 3 [0, 2, 3, 1] [Fraction(0, 1), Fraction(7, 4), Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(-1, 3)] [0, 2, 3, 1]
>
> 4 [0, 3, 1, 2] [Fraction(0, 1), Fraction(33, 4), Fraction(-13, 2), Fraction(4, 3)] [0, 3, 1, 2]
>
> 5 [0, 3, 2, 1] [Fraction(0, 1), Fraction(19, 3), Fraction(-4, 1), Fraction(2, 3)] [0, 3, 2, 1]
>
> 6 [1, 0, 2, 3] [Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(-15, 4), Fraction(7, 2), Fraction(-2, 3)] [1, 0, 2, 3]
>
> 7 [1, 0, 3, 2] [Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(-17, 3), Fraction(6, 1), Fraction(-4, 3)] [1, 0, 3, 2]
>
> 8 [1, 2, 0, 3] [Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(21, 4), Fraction(-11, 2), Fraction(4, 3)] [1, 2, 0, 3]
>
> 9 [1, 2, 3, 0] [Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(-1, 3), Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(-2, 3)] [1, 2, 3, 0]
>
> 10 [1, 3, 0, 2] [Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(31, 4), Fraction(-15, 2), Fraction(5, 3)] [1, 3, 0, 2]
>
> 11 [1, 3, 2, 0] [Fraction(1, 1), Fraction(17, 4), Fraction(-5, 2), Fraction(1, 3)] [1, 3, 2, 0]
>
> 12 [2, 0, 1, 3] [Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(-17, 4), Fraction(5, 2), Fraction(-1, 3)] [2, 0, 1, 3]
>
> 13 [2, 0, 3, 1] [Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(-31, 4), Fraction(15, 2), Fraction(-5, 3)] [2, 0, 3, 1]
>
> 14 [2, 1, 0, 3] [Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(-2, 1), Fraction(2, 3)] [2, 1, 0, 3]
>
> 15 [2, 1, 3, 0] [Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(-21, 4), Fraction(11, 2), Fraction(-4, 3)] [2, 1, 3, 0]
>
> 16 [2, 3, 0, 1] [Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(17, 3), Fraction(-6, 1), Fraction(4, 3)] [2, 3, 0, 1]
>
> 17 [2, 3, 1, 0] [Fraction(2, 1), Fraction(15, 4), Fraction(-7, 2), Fraction(2, 3)] [2, 3, 1, 0]
>
> 18 [3, 0, 1, 2] [Fraction(3, 1), Fraction(-19, 3), Fraction(4, 1), Fraction(-2, 3)] [3, 0, 1, 2]
>
> 19 [3, 0, 2, 1] [Fraction(3, 1), Fraction(-33, 4), Fraction(13, 2), Fraction(-4, 3)] [3, 0, 2, 1]
>
> 20 [3, 1, 0, 2] [Fraction(3, 1), Fraction(-7, 4), Fraction(-1, 2), Fraction(1, 3)] [3, 1, 0, 2]
>
> 21 [3, 1, 2, 0] [Fraction(3, 1), Fraction(-11, 2), Fraction(9, 2), Fraction(-1, 1)] [3, 1, 2, 0]
>
> 22 [3, 2, 0, 1] [Fraction(3, 1), Fraction(3, 4), Fraction(-5, 2), Fraction(2, 3)] [3, 2, 0, 1]
>
> 23 [3, 2, 1, 0] [Fraction(3, 1), Fraction(-1, 1), Fraction(0, 1), Fraction(0, 1)] [3, 2, 1, 0]

We can see clearly that there is a symmetry: coefs[i] = [3 - coefs[23-i][0]] + [-c for c in coefs[23-i][1:]] so it's a way to explore but I have no clue that it's possible.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Try not computing `factorial(f)` three times each step? If you set some variable `fact = factorial(f)` at the beginning, then you can just divide it by `f` in the first step, then by `f-1`, then `f-2`, and so on.

Comment: @Nelfeal yes this was just an example, in my original function factorials are precomputed... I just want to get rid of the whole while loop.

Comment: I believe you can't

Answer (score 4):

You can find the `n`-th permutation by doing repeated euclidean division (quotient and remainder, aka divmod) and keeping track of what letters you pick. You can then pick the `i`-th letter from that permutation.

Let `S` be a copy of the initial string, `L` the length of that string and `P` the number of permutations (`L!`). `T` will be the `n`-th permutation of `S`, constructed step-by-step.
Example: `S = "ABCD"`, `L = 4`, and `P = 24`. Let's take `n = 15` for the example. `T` should be `"CBDA"` at the end.

Set `P = P/L`. Compute `divmod(n, P)`, let `q` be the quotient (`n/P`) and `r` the remainder (`n%P`). Remove the `q`-th letter from `S` and append it to `T`. Set `n = r`, decrement `L`, and repeat until `L = 0`.
Example:
1) `P = 24/4 = 6`, `q = 15/6 = 2`, `r = 15%6 = 3`, `S = "ABD"`, `T = "C"`, `n = r = 3`, `L = 3`.
2) `P = 6/3 = 2`, `q = 3/2 = 1`, `r = 3%2 = 1`, `S = "AD"`, `T = "CB"`, `n = r = 1`, `L = 2`.
3) `P = 2/2 = 1`, `q = 1/1 = 1`, `r = 1%1 = 0`, `S = "A"`, `T = "CBD"`, `n = r = 0`, `L = 1`.
4) `P = 1/1 = 1`, `q = 0/1 = 0`, `r = 0%1 = 0`, `S = ""`, `T = "CBDA"`, `n = r = 0`, `L = 0`.

Since you only want the `i`-th letter, you can stop whenever the length of `T` equals `i+1` and take that last letter.

I won't try to code this in Python because it's been too long since I've touched Python, but [here is a demo in C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b83538cf7d1b03b0).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I already have such a function in python, i was wondering if some straight forward equivalence can be done...

Comment: But this is a straightforward equivalence. It only has `L` steps and can be reversed (also in `L` steps). I'm pretty sure you won't get anything more straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, for my Python. The idea is that letter at every positions repeats `(number_of_pos - pos)!` times.

E.g. `ABCD`, letter at the first position would repeat `3!` times. So, by dividing `n` by this factorial we now which letter is in the first position. To find letter in the second position we need to remove this letter from the set (assign `0` instead) and update `n` with `n - n % 3!` to now index of letter in the second position. When applying this index we need to take care not to count letter which is in the first position.

Complexity is `O(kPosCount * kPosCount)`.

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

const int kPosCount = 4;
const std::array<int, kPosCount> factorial = { 1,1,2,6 };
const std::array<int, kPosCount> kLetters = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' };

char f(int pos, int n) {
    assert(pos < kPosCount);
    std::array<int, kPosCount> letters = kLetters;

    int res = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= pos; ++i) {
        const int letter = n / factorial[kPosCount - i - 1];
        int j = 0;
        for (int stillThere = 0; j < kPosCount; ++j) {
            if (letters[j] != 0) {
                if (stillThere == letter) {
                    break;
                }
                ++stillThere;
            }
        }
        letters[j] = 0;
        res = j;
        n %= factorial[kPosCount - i - 1];
    }
    return kLetters[res];
}

int main() {
    const int kMaxN = factorial.back() * kPosCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < kPosCount; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < kMaxN; ++j) {
            std::cout << f(i, j) << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of your function with a different permutation order. I didn't force the size of the permutation to be 256 here, so you have to supply it as the first argument.

```
def elt(n,k,i):
  """Returns element i of permutation k from permutations of length n"""
  perm = [*range(n)]
  for j in range(i+1):
    k, r = divmod(k, n-j)
    perm[j], perm[j+r] = perm[j+r], perm[j]
  return perm[i]
```

That has two differences from your code.

First, the digits are carved off of the index from right-to-left, which means that the bignum divmods are all divmods by a small dividend. I thought that would be faster than using a bignum dividend, but it turns out to be significantly slower. However, it does avoid having to precompute the factorials.

Second, rather than doing a series of `pop`s from the middle of a table, which is going to be of quadratic complexity because the pop operation is O(n), I just swap each element with some forward element. That's significantly faster, although the bignum arithmetic dominates the computation.

In effect, `elt(n,k,i)` does the first `i` steps in a Fisher-Yates shuffle of `range(n)` using the mixed-base decomposition of `k` as what would be the random values in a random shuffle. Since the F-Y shuffle produces a different result for each possible sequence of random values, and the mixed-base decomposition of `k` produces a different sequence for each different value of `k`, all permutations will be generated.

Here's what the order looks like for n=4:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(elt(4, k, i)) for i in range(4))
                    for k in range(factorial(4))))
0 1 2 3
1 0 2 3
2 1 0 3
3 1 2 0
0 2 1 3
1 2 0 3
2 0 1 3
3 2 1 0
0 3 2 1
1 3 2 0
2 3 0 1
3 0 2 1
0 1 3 2
1 0 3 2
2 1 3 0
3 1 0 2
0 2 3 1
1 2 3 0
2 0 3 1
3 2 0 1
0 3 1 2
1 3 0 2
2 3 1 0
3 0 1 2
```

To actually speed up the function, I reintroduced the precomputed factorials (as an local variable which is extended as necessary). I also micro-optimised the inner loop by removing as much arithmetic as possible, which meant doing the F-Y shuffle from back to front. This results in yet another permutation order; see below for an example.

The final optimised function is about 15% faster than the version in the question (that is, it takes about 85% of the time to do a simple benchmark).

```
def elt_opt(n, k, i, fact=[1]):
    """Returns element i of permutation k from permutations of length n.
       Let the last argument default.
    """
    while len(fact) < n: fact.append(fact[-1]*len(fact))
    perm = list(range(n))
    for j in range(n-1, n-2-i, -1):
        r, k = divmod(k, fact[j])
        perm[j], perm[r] = perm[r], perm[j]
    return perm[n-i-1]
```

Permutation order:

```
>>> print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(elt_opt(4, k, i)) for i in range(4))
                    for k in range(factorial(4))))
0 3 2 1
0 3 1 2
0 1 3 2
0 1 2 3
0 2 3 1
0 2 1 3
1 0 2 3
1 0 3 2
1 3 0 2
1 3 2 0
1 2 0 3
1 2 3 0
2 0 3 1
2 0 1 3
2 1 0 3
2 1 3 0
2 3 0 1
2 3 1 0
3 0 2 1
3 0 1 2
3 1 0 2
3 1 2 0
3 2 0 1
3 2 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the stuff about Fisher-Yates is very interesting and also generating permutations without computing factorials! But after benchmarking I found this solution is a bit slower than mine. No idea why, maybe python 3.7 is better to handle list.pop()

Comment: @fbparis: turns out that I was wrong about division; python is actually about 60% faster dividing two bignums with a small quotient than dividing a bignum by a small dividend. That overwhelms the speedup of swapping.

Comment: @fbparis: I added the most optimised version I could come up with. But it's not hugely faster than yours.

Comment: well done (I'm closer to 10% speed improvement) but it's still not suitable for the intended usage, I guess I need something < O(n). I strongly doubt it's possible but I will keep trying new things a little (I'm currently testing stuff using Lagrange Interpolations...)

Comment: @fbparis: i don't believe sub-linear exists but you might be able to reformulate your problem in some way. For example, if you need more than one element from the same permutation, all but one of them are free. So that could help a lot

Comment: there is another way to improve it using symmetry of the permutations so that we never loop more than N // 2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186154/discussion-between-fbparis-and-rici).

Comment: @fbparis. Sure, but the bignums are bigger at the beginning of the loop so the first iterationd are the slowest. Still, I have a hard time imagining a use case where you only ever need one element of a designated permutation.